# Flutter - Shortcut Key for Quickly Select an Entire Widget in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, keyboard-shortcuts

For Developing flutter Application, In Android Studio `ctrl+W` selects an entire Widget.

But in Visual Studio I can't find any Shortcut... Is there any shortcut to do what exactly android studio does?

Comment: In Android Studio, put cursor on or immediately before the Widget, then `option + up arrow` once or twice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here what i found on this site[link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-visual-studio-code-shortcuts-for-fast-and-efficient-development-7235bc6c3b7d)

First click on either of the start braces or the ending braces and then click Shift+Alt+→ and magically all the things inside those braces will be selected, you can keep on pressing Shift+Alt+→ to expand the selection more and you can also shrink the selection by using Shift+Alt+←

Answer (score 2):

There is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FushiArt.copywidget) in vscode. It enables the same functionality you wanted on Android Studio. `Alt + W` or `Opt + W` to select whole widget.

Comment: This extension does nothing for me. Simply does not work.

Comment: Extension still works for me on Mac. I'm not sure about Windows.

Comment: @Ataberk even for mac not working

Comment: @samadshukr In shortcut settings, can you attach `Highlight a widget` command to option + w?

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode, if you are trying to duplicate the selected code, if you do what @reza47 says then while all of the code is selected do Shift+Alt+downarrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Setting** in VsCode and in **Keyboard Shortcuts** search **Refactor**. After you change this in order what you want you can use it to select entire Widget.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just put the cursor on the widget and keep on pressing [SHIFT]+[ALT]+[->]. You can either do it from beginning braces of the widget or from the ending as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So on Mac selecting after placing the cursor in front of the widget you wish to select. pressing the buttons ctrl + shift + cmd + right will select the intended widget.You may have to press right multiple times. You can shrink and expand widget selection at will. This information can be found on the Selection Tab for vs-code.

UPDATE: after continuous experimentation, ctrl + shift + left/right works just as well.